# Fatal error while trying to require_once() a file in the same directory

Tags: php, ubuntu, require

Here is the directory hierarchy:

[image: hierarchy]

The file `cron_requests.php` looks like:

```
require_once '/autoload.php';

$request_status = isset($_REQUEST['request']) ? (new _cron)->handler($_REQUEST['request']) : false ;
```

It tries to load a PHP file named `autoload.php`, but while doing so, I get an error thrown:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/autoload.php'
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/Cron/cron_requests.php
on line 7
```

What could be the reason for this error? Is it not the correct way to require a file?

**This works fine on windows**

Comment: remove the leading `/`, you are requesting the file `autoload.php` from the root of the filesystem

Comment: (.) dot slash require_once './autoload.php'; try this

Comment: alternatively you could try : `require_once __DIR__.'/autoload.php';`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the leading `/` when requiring the `autoload.php` file as the file is in the *same* DIR.

Change,

```
require_once '/autoload.php';
```

To,

```
require_once 'autoload.php';
```

A more absolute way would be to use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) before your file name like,

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';
```

`__DIR__`

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(**FILE**). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.

Comment: @Karooka This should work on Windows, it works for me and I use Windows.

Comment: I am to work in windows with `require_once '/autoload.php';`. Why is that?

Comment: @Karooka You wrote: *"PS: This works fine on windows"* - I for one am baffled by your *"How does it work in windows then?"* comment here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What was error in ubuntu works fine in Windows. So, when I do `require_once '/autoload.php'`, it throws an error in ubuntu but not in windows. That is what I meant, when I wrote `PS: This works fine on windows"`

Comment: @Karooka I posted a comment under your question earlier and deleted it since I felt it was either ignored or of no importance. If you're on a \*NIX system, `Cron` and `cron` and `File.php` and `file.php` are two different animals, should the filenaming convention be the case here.

Comment: You can also use `require_once './autoload.php';` to include a file from the current directory.